# how to separate overlapped patterns

Tags: regex

I have a header file which contains several struct definitions.
I want to extract a spesific struct from this file. For example
I need to get only second struct.

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} first;

typedef struct {
  int x;
 int y;
} second;
```

Below expression

```
...
headerText = headerFile.read()
re.match(r"typedef struct {(.*)} second;", headerText) 
...
```

returns

```
int a;
  int b;
} first;

typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
```

How can I get only the second struct?
Thanks...

Comment: Use [non-greedy `.*?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: u need to specify the language u r using

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It: Oh, you're right. I've missed the `second` thing - then you'll need to use `[^}]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `regex`..just replace the `second` with any other required struct name

**[without groups]**

Use this regex if you dont want the groups

```
typedef struct(?!.*?typedef struct).*?\}.*?\bsecond\b.*?;
```

The above regex matches `typedef struct` that is not followed by another `typedef struct` i.e. `(?!.*?typedef struct)`..This is done so that multiple structs are not captured

---

**[with groups]**

```
(?:^|\;).*(typedef struct.*?\}.*?\bsecond\b.*?;)
```

Basically the above `regex` matches a struct that is either at the start of the file or it would match the required struct after a statement terminator..i.e `;`.This is done so that other struct definitions are not included in the result..

`(?:^|\;)` matches the start of the string or a `;` and doesnt get captured in the group

`.*` matches 0 to many characters **greedily**

`(typedef struct.*?\}.*?\bsecond\b.*?;)` now matches your struct

`.*?` matches 0 to many characters **lazily**

`Group1` now has your required struct

Comment: Could you explain this expression? It's seems very complex for me.

Comment: @user1320039 check out the edit..the second regex would be easy to understand

Comment: "with groups" example worked but "without groups" example not worked.

Comment: @user1320039 select DOTALL option in the above link